# How to get timezone information from geolocation in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic5

I am using @ionic-native/geolocation/ngx plugin to get coordinates of the current location. Is there a plugin to get country and time zone based on geolocation? For instance, Country code = "NZ", Time zone = "Pacific/Auckland".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a time zone from a location using latitude and longitude coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates)

Comment: I had a look at it already - thanks. I am looking for an offline version specifically for ionic.